# How to change XML attribute value?

Tags: c++, xml, attributes, xerces

I want change an attribute value of a XML file.

I already change a node value, in this manner:

```
xercesc_3_2::XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();

xercesc_3_2::XercesDOMParser* parser = new xercesc_3_2::XercesDOMParser;
parser->setValidationScheme(xercesc_3_2::XercesDOMParser::Val_Never);
parser->parse(fileName.c_str());

xercesc_3_2::DOMDocument* doc = parser->getDocument();

xercesc_3_2::DOMElement* root = doc->getDocumentElement();

xercesc_3_2::DOMXPathResult* result = doc->evaluate(
    xercesc_3_2::XMLString::transcode("/document/child1/child2"),
    root,
    NULL,
    xercesc_3_2::DOMXPathResult::ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    NULL);
result->getNodeValue()->getFirstChild()->setNodeValue(xercesc_3_2::XMLString::transcode(value.c_str()));
```

But I don't understand how to change the attribute value.

How can I do?

Comment: Like `setNodeValue`, there's also `DOMElement::setAttribute`, documentation [here](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMElement.html#a1a607d8c619c4aa4a59bc1a7bc5d4692)

Comment: Wrong. I use xercesc_3_2::DOMXPathResult* result, I need to access to the attribute list with DOMXPathResult

Comment: Well, you'd still need to use `getNodeValue` like you do in your existing code. And then it'll depend on your exact xpath query what you do with that. If the query evaluates to an attribute node, you can use DOMAttribute methods on it. If it evaluates to an element whose attribute you want to change, I mentioned the setAttribute function.

Comment: I'm starting to understand what do you mean, but I don't know how to write it in code. Can you provide me a code example?

I have to change this call:
xercesc_3_2::DOMXPathResult* result = doc->evaluate(
  xercesc_3_2::XMLString::transcode(node.c_str()),
  root,
  NULL,
  xercesc_3_2::DOMXPathResult::ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
  NULL);

Comment: result->getNodeValue()->hasAttributes() return true, so detect the attribute but I don't know how to read/modify it